# Disable creation of labels in Jira?

Tags: prometheus, jira

Following the base instructions I can't create new Jira item through API request due to failing because of trying to create labels. Even if I am using  add_group_labels: false it tries to create label anyway, isn't this option supposed to disable this behavior? From what I read I need to allow the user to create labels through rest api, but I just don't want the albels on the ticket.

Testing with:
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"receiver": "prometheus-customer-non-production", "status": "firing", "alerts": [{"status": "firing", "labels": {"alertname": "TestAlert", "key": "value"} }], "groupLabels": {"alertname": "TestAlert"}}' http://xx.x.xxx.xx:9097/alert

Output:
{"Error":true,"Status":500,"Message":"JIRA request https://customer.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue returned status 400 Bad Request, body \"{\\"errorMessages\\":[],\\"errors\\":{\\"labels\\":\\"Field 'labels' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.\\"}}\""}

Here is the configuration jiralert.yaml:

```
# Global defaults, applied to all receivers where not explicitly overridden. Optional.
defaults:
  # API access fields.
  api_url: https://customer.atlassian.net
  user: 'example@customer.com'
  password: 'customerpassword'

  # The type of JIRA issue to create. Required.
  issue_type: Alert
  # Issue priority. Optional.
  # priority: Low
  # Go template invocation for generating the summary. Required.
  summary: '{{ template "jira.summary" . }}'
  # Go template invocation for generating the description. Optional.
  description: '{{ template "jira.description" . }}'
  # State to transition into when reopening a closed issue. Required.
  reopen_state: "To Do"
  # Do not reopen issues with this resolution. Optional.
  wont_fix_resolution: "Won't Fix"
  # Amount of time after being closed that an issue should be reopened, after which, a new issue is created.
  # Optional (default: always reopen)
  reopen_duration: 0h

# Receiver definitions. At least one must be defined.
receivers:
    # Must match the Alertmanager receiver name. Required.
  - name: 'prometheus-customer-non-production'
    # JIRA project to create the issue in. Required.
    project: customer
    # Copy all Prometheus labels into separate JIRA labels. Optional (default: false).
    add_group_labels: false

# File containing template definitions. Required.
template: jiralert.tmpl
```

Below you can find versions info:

Package release utilized -> https://github.com/prometheus-community/jiralert/releases/download/1.0/jiralert-1.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz

```
cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:36:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
helm list prometheus-operator --tiller-namespace=monitoring
NAME                    REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                           APP VERSION     NAMESPACE
prometheus-operator     3               Thu Apr  9 16:44:37 2020        DEPLOYED        prometheus-operator-8.12.12     0.37.0          monitoring
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the github reply I received, it looks only way is to allow it in Jira as it will spam same alert otherwise:

> Labels are how JIRAlert matches alerts to tickets. Without them, it
>   would simply create a new ticket every time it gets called by
>   Alertmanager for the same alert, i.e. once every few minutes.
>
> If I understand the error correctly, it looks like you'll have to
>   enable labels for your JIRA project. I don't have admin access to a
>   JIRA instance, so I can't tell you exactly how to do that.